# Why "Textbox.Paste" can only appear on left hand side of += or -= in XAML, C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm currently developing an web browser for Windows 10 and i get this error :

> "Textbox.Paste" can only appear on left hand side of += or -=

I'm currently adding ability to paste content of URL in textbox and it doesn't work. I was doing like this :

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SearchBox_Paste(object sender, TextControlPasteEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchBox.Paste = true;
    }
}
```

}

Where i'm doing wrong ? I'm C# beginner and this is my first project. Thanks for kind answers and please bear in mind that i'm beginner ! Cheers !

Comment: `SearchBox.Paste` is an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/awbftdfh.aspx). What are you trying to do with that code?

Comment: `TextBox` _already_ has the ability to paste - you don't need to _add_ it.  In fact, it is difficult to turn _off_ that ability completely.

Comment: I have a text box which will have ability of Cut , Copy and Paste function. I'm developing web browser and if i press F7 to view code, i need to set that up. How do i add that ability ?

Comment: Go in Keypress event, not in Paste again.

Comment: @AppsWorkshop Read my comment again - it already has that capability. The `Paste` _event_ lets you run some code when the user _does_ paste text.  It has no effect on the _ability_ to paste code. If you are not _able_ to paste then post your XAML.

Comment: I'll try, so let's see results :)

Comment: The title says "Textbox.Paste", the code says "Searchbox.Paste", and I don't see any += or -= anywhere in the code example...

Comment: @Taegost - the `TextBox.Paste` is the event on the base object (being a `TextBox`). My guess is that `SearchBox` is the `x:Name` of the object in the Xaml (which is of type `<TextBox/>`), and that's why this error is appearing like it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Textbox.Paste" can only appear on left hand side of += or -=

The `TextBox.Paste` is an `event` (`TextBox` is referring to the UIElement type) - ergo `SearchBox` a derivative of this type

You will need to subscribe this event, and hook up a handler to perform some work, when the event is fired. What you do in your handler is up to you.

You can subscribe by using `SearchBox.Paste +=`, and declaring a handler of your own (or VS can do this for you). Inversely, you can unsubscribe with `SearchBox.Paste -=`

As an example, your code would want to look something like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SearchBox.Paste += SearchBox_Paste; // Subscribe to the Paste event
    }

    private void SearchBox_Paste(object sender, TextControlPasteEventArgs e)
    {
        // The code in here will be fired when the SearchBox.Paste event is raised

        // Do something in here, when text is pasted to the SearchBox.
        // You can use the e parameter to see more data about the event
    }
}
```

Any questions, just ask!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: As a useful tip - when you're using Intellisense in VS (I assume that you are), you will see a lightning bolt defining which object's member are events :)

Comment: I'm currently loading in an emulator so let's see does it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it because the [Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.paste.aspx) in a TextBox is not a property but an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) of the control which is launched when text is pasted on the control.

> The Paste event occurs before any content is inserted into the
>   control. You can handle this event to check the contents of the
>   clipboard and perform any actions on the content before it's inserted.
>   If you perform any action, set the Handled property of the event args
>   to true; otherwise, the default paste action is performed. If you mark
>   the event as handled, then it's assumed the app has handled the paste
>   operation, and no default action is performed. You are responsible for
>   determining the insertion point and clipboard content to insert, and
>   inserting the content.

Therefore, you can only subscribe (`+=`) or unsuscribe (`-=`) on the event, but not set values to it.

Simple example:

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Header="Address" Paste="AddressTextBox_Paste"/>
```

**CS**

```
private async void AddressTextBox_Paste(object sender, TextControlPasteEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox addressBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (addressBox != null)
    {
        // Mark the event as handled first. Otherwise, the
        // default paste action will happen, then the custom paste
        // action, and the user will see the text box content change.
        e.Handled = true;

        // Get content from the clipboard.
        var dataPackageView = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent();
        if (dataPackageView.Contains(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                var text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();

                // Remove line breaks from multi-line text and
                // replace with comma(,).
                string singleLineText = text.Replace("\r\n", ", ");

                // Replace any text currently in the text box.
                addressBox.Text = singleLineText;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore or handle exception as needed.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to add cut and copy, and also ability to search url ? I've added WebView already.

Comment: You can do that by default in any textbox control. If you have another question, please open it as such.

Comment: Okay, that's enough. I'll ask later for WebView, i'll learn by time :)

Comment: @NahuelIanni I think you done as much effort as you could do. But he seems very naive at language and its beyond him to grasp I think. +1 for your neat answer!

Comment: Ok i have a problem. I loaded app in Emulator and textbox is too big ! How can i set size to automatic if possible, app is too big to use !

Answer (score 0):

`Paste` is an event of `SearchBox`. You need to make/use a delegate here. You can't use assignment operator with it

Comment: How do i do that ?

Comment: Oh cool ! So how do i add other abilities (search URL, copy and paste) in textbox ?

Comment: Copy and Paste is also already there! I would suggest you to read the documentation on (WPF) TextBox first

Comment: @TalhaIrfan That link is for the winforms textbox, not the WPF textbox.

Comment: Ouch! Deleted the link.

Comment: I have another question : How do i make Search work in SearchBox (Textbox) ? Do i need to add WebView then add a line of code to Search url for it ? Thanks ! @TalhaIrfan